# List Item background in scrollable UL

Tags: html, css

I have a scrollable ul and the list items have a background. For some reason the background fills only the initial visible area. If I scroll down it disappears :

http://jsfiddle.net/sirrocco/9z48t/

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<ul class="list">
    <li class="item1">     
        <span> my text </span>
        <img src="https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-ash4/373049_39875583837_702729249_q.jpg"/>
    </li>
    <li class="item2">
        <span> my text text text text </span>
        <img src="https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-ash4/373049_39875583837_702729249_q.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li class="item3">
        <span> my text text text text </span>
        <img src="https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-ash4/373049_39875583837_702729249_q.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li class="item4">
        <span> my text </span>
                    <span> my text </span>          <span> my text </span>          <span> my text </span>          <span> my text </span>          <span> my text </span>          <span> my text </span>          <span> my text </span>          <span> my text </span>          <span> my text </span>          <span> my text </span>          <span> my text </span>          <span> my text </span>          <span> my text </span>          <span> my text </span>          <span> my text </span>          <span> my text </span>v         <span> my text </span>          <span> my text </span>          <span> my text </span>          <span> my text </span>
        <img src="https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-ash4/373049_39875583837_702729249_q.jpg" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
html,body{
    height: 100%
}
#wrapper {
    background: transparent;
    width: 550px;
    color: white;
    height:100%;
}
#wrapper ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    background: green;
    height:50%;
    overflow-y:auto;
    width: 100%;
}
#wrapper ul > li {
    width: 50px;
    display:block;
    float: left;
    background: black;
    border-radius: 25px 25px 0 0;
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    height:100%;
}
#wrapper ul > li span {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;

}
#wrapper ul > li img {
    display: block;
    float:left;
}
```

How can this be fixed ?

Thanks.

**More Details:**

All columns must be the same height: So if one is really long because it has a lot of text in it, then all need to be that long.

Comment: You might need flexbox or css tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want them to be the same size :

http://jsfiddle.net/9z48t/4/

Then set `display:table-row` to the container(`#wrapper ul`) and `display:table-cell` to the inner elements (`#wrapper ul > li`);

Comment: Well they all need to be the same height. So that wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
#wrapper ul > li {
    width: 50px;
    display:block;
    float: left;
    background: black;
    border-radius: 25px 25px 0 0;
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    **height:auto;**
}
```

Change height 100% to auto.